# Using Wilkinson's Catalyst to reduce esters?

Tags: alcohols, esters, organic-reduction

I was solving some questions on alcohols when I came upon a question in which it was asked that whether esters can be reduced  using hydrogen in the prescence of wilkinson's catalyst.

Now I know that this reaction can take place using hydrogen in the prescence of nickel or platinum to give two alcohols.So is the same true for using wilkinson's catalyst also?

And if it cannot be so then on which functional groups can this be used on?

Also what would happen differently if wilkinson's catalyst is used?

Comment: https://aocs.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1007/BF02678792